# Does Java JVM reuse identical immutable instances of custom classes like it does with String?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, jvm

If you create the String "codecodecode" anew in a hundred places, in reality **it will only exist once**, because the JVM optimizes like this.

But what about this class:

```
final public class ImmutReuseTest {

    final public int num;
    final public SomeImmutableThing thing;

    public ImmutReuseTest(final int num, final SomeImmutableThing thing) {
        this.num = num;
        this.thing = thing;
    }

}

final public class SomeImmutableThing {

    final public int nomm;
    final public String text;

    public SomeImmutableThing(final int nomm, final String text) {
        this.nomm = nomm;
        this.text = text;
    }

}
```

1. If I create thousands of instances of ImmutReuseTest, of which some will have 100% **equal** values, will the JVM optimize those equal ones like it does with String? ("Equal" meaning: The individual fields are equal between the instances, and this in regards to the field of type "SomeImmutableThing" means: Those thing fields are also equal between those thing instances.)
2. What about if the instances have the exact **identical** values? ("Identical" meaning: The SomeImmutableThing instances are the same instead of just being equal.)
3. What if we change SomeImmutableThing to use a class that is considered immutable, but has internal mutable values (like String does, but String is a bad example because of the dedicated JVM optimization)? E.g. let's use one that has public mutable fields but is "effectively final". Or one that only has private mutable fields which are "effectively final".

Comment: About point 2: If multiple references point to the same instance, then that is obviously only one object. The reference itself takes up space (the 'heap position') but the instance is usually not copied, unless an API does so explicitly, or a copy-method or function creates a new equal object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution environment has to retain the semantics of the Java programming language, i.e. [of the `new` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

This doesn’t depend on the mutability of your class and as long as Java offers no other way to instantiate your class than with `new`, there will be no sharing of instances except when you have implemented it yourself.

The known cases where you will (or might) end up with reused objects do not involve `new`, e.g.

```java
String s = "foo";
Integer i = 42;
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("hello");
```

Further, for types with intentionally unspecified object identity, like [Value-based Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html), instances are always acquired through factory methods, so the way they are actually instantiated is not visible to the application.

For true value types, as being planed to be added in a future Java version, we’d need either, a new syntax construct for creating/getting an instance or a language specification change regarding the `new` operator.

A JVM may still do any optimization it wants, as long as it doesn’t change the program logic, so if it can prove that the application never performs an identity sensitive operation on certain objects or can pretend that those operations still have the same effect (e.g. `new Foo() == new Foo()` could be replaced with `false`), it can fold identical objects into one. That’s obviously very hard or almost impossible to prove.

Currently, it can be done for short lived objects when the entirely lifetime is within the optimizer’s horizon. However, in those cases, the JVM will eliminate the allocation completely, instead of searching for identical objects to reuse. See [HotSpot Wiki/Escape Analysis](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/EscapeAnalysis)…

Answer (score 0):

> If I create thousands of instances of ImmutReuseTest, of which some will have 100% equal values, will the JVM optimize those equal ones like it does with String?

The answer is no. Writing a class to be immutable does not impact how the JVM manages its instances. Java's [value types](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169), as part of Project Valhalla, aims to address that issue though. The `String` optimization is really a special case.

> What about if the instances have the exact identical values? ("Identical" meaning: The SomeImmutableThing instances are the same instead of just being equal.)

Yes in this case, there is only one instance with that identity.

Not sure I understand your last question, but it doesn't seem to differ from the first one.